# How to stream a map which is a field in a list object into another map?

Tags: java, list, java-stream, maps, collectors

```
public class ProductFamilyProcessUI implements Comparable {
    private String id;
    private int seqNo;
    private DepartmentUI department;
    private ProcessGroupUI processGroup;
    private ProcessUI process;
    private ProcessFlowType processFlowType;
    private Map<String, OutsourceToStatusEnum> outSourceToStatuses;
}
```

The ProductFamilyProcessUI is a list that I get in a request, I want to stream the outsourceToStatuses into another map of the same type.

```
Map<String, OutsourceToStatusEnum> outsourceToStatusEnumMap = productFamilyProcessUIList1
    .stream()
    .map(ProductFamilyProcessUI::getOutSourceToStatuses)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap());
```

I tried this but it expects input in Collectors.toMap().

Comment: tried something? [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67344742/edit) to update your attempt

Comment: Map<String, OutsourceToStatusEnum> outsourceToStatusEnumMap = productFamilyProcessUIList1.stream().map(ProductFamilyProcessUI::getOutSourceToStatuses).collect(Collectors.toMap();
I tried this but it expects an input in Collectors.toMap().

Comment: replace `.map(ProductFamilyProcessUI::getOutSourceToStatuses)` with `.map(pf -> pf.getOutSourceToStatuses().entrySet().stream)` and then while collecting provide keyTransformer, value transformer from an `Map.Entry` as a source to the `toMap` API.

Comment: apart from the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)), the duplicates shall help you transform your code looking at examples.

Comment: What is keyTransformer and value Transformer? I didn't understand. Can you please explain how to do this?

Comment: They are both `Function`s to map your elements from the stream to another object. The links provide good enough code to relate with examples.